# How to create a simulink signal read from csv file at run time

Tags: matlab, csv, simulink, qemu

I have a QEMU ARM CPU running and toggle PIN (by GPIO Model) and dump the values at run time on a CSV File (Kindly note, tat the signal values is changing at runtime). So I need to make a simulink Model which is polling on this CSV File and read the (time/value) and generate Matlab simulink signal to connect to scope as shown on the attached image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use Simulink for this?  Most of the code required will need to be written in MATLAB anyway, and the time on the Simulink scope will not reflect the time that the data is read, so why not just use a MATLAB figure?

Comment: because then i need to connect  simulink Signal with motores and other simulink Models.
i need any way any method to get signal from the QEMU to SImulink at runtime / Maybe (polling on file) or (server/client sockets) or (tcp/ip port)

i can write a C Code On QEMU but how the C Code can be export signal at run time to the simulink

Answer (score 0):

i success to pull on a file inside Simulink and read a signal value 
but i don't know how to block or generate this value signal at specific time

```
function y=fcn()
fprintf('XD\n');
fifo_in = 'C:\Users\kkhalil\Desktop\matlab.ipc-master\matlab.ipc-master\fifo1.txt';
fin = fopen(fifo_in, 'r');

fprintf('reading...\n');
nData =  fread(fin, 1, 'uint8=>char') ;

data = uint8(nData)-48 ;
fclose(fin);
y =  uint8(data);
```

[image]